# How to serve the local PHP file and database in Wamp Server to WAN i.e. person from other network?

Tags: php, mysql, database, server, wamp

My website is currently hosted in wix.com, I have a domain name but don't know how to serve the PHP web pages which are currently in `http://192.168.1.14/test/loginandsignup.php` with my system's IP address `192.168.1.14` and wamp server is installed in my system.

My problem is what I do next to serve these files for any person outside my network if I make my window 10 system to serve these PHP files.

Please help to give directions.

Comment: You cannot serve a website from a local address in the 192.n.n.n range publicly. You have to transfer the files from your machine to the web server.

Comment: can we do some port forwarding for global IP address to the local IP address.

Comment: "My website is currently hosted in wix.com" Not if the files are only on your local computer.

Comment: You could do some port forwarding and other network magic, but why would you do that? Do you really want to host your website from a local machine?

Comment: Actually i have some php files for employee timesheet and i just need to get the public IP address of assigned to my router to serve these local php files in my system.

Comment: Are you going to leave your computer switched on all day and night so the site is always available? How many users will connect to it - will it become overloaded with users and make it too slow for you to use? Do you have enough upstream bandwidth on your home internet connection to support the usage? In my opinion if you want to make this for real use (and not just testing or demo) then find a hosting company which supports you adding PHP code to your site (which wix does not). There are literally thousands of hosting companies which provide such a service.

Comment: But if you really want to make the pages available from your local machine just for a demonstration or something, then log into your router and configure its port forwarding settings. You might also want to make use of a dynamic DNS service so you get a hostname for the site, and you don't have to keep checking that the IP address is still correct (most domestic internet providers will not give you a permanent IP address, instead it usually gets changed after a period of time, and/or when you reset your router. One reason they do this is to make home-hosting difficult!).

Comment: amazing this cleared my query and left me speechless

Comment: speechless? why? Is the problem solved?

Comment: Yes i found the solution that port forwarding or Buying domain name can solve my problem. Thanks